# Replace неизвестного знака

Tags: php

есть &1 &2 &3 &n

и как с помощью str_replace() убрать & и 1 символ который после него?

str_replace("&(тутлюбойсимвол)", "");

Чтобы не дублировать и не реплейсить все &1 &2 &3 &n

Comment: используйте `preg_replace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найдите и заменить на пустоту амперсанд и один любой символ после него, например, так:

```
php > echo preg_replace("/&./", "", "foo &1 bar &2baz");
foo  bar baz
```